# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Client-Side Validation HOWTO

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

Where can I find some good information on the new client-side validation functionality included in ASP.NET MVC v2?

I'd like to find information about using the client-side validation JavaScript without using DataAnnotations, and I'd like to find out how custom validations are handled.

For example, if I want to validate two fields together, how would I utilize the provided JavaScript? Or if I wanted to write validation code on the server-side that queried a database, how could I use the provided JavaScript to implement a similar validation?

I don't see any books on MVC2 yet, and the blog entries I've found are not detailed enough.

Answer (score 2):

DataAnnotations have limits. You can easily apply simple [validation rules on independent model properties and enable client side validation](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) but if you need to handle more advanced scenarios such as dependent properties you will need more robust frameworks such as [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) or [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This is another good summary of what is in the framework to start with: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 20-minute video demonstration.

> [10-4 Episode 37: Leveraging
>   Model Metadata and Validation with
>   ASP.NET MVC2](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-37-Leveraging-Model-Metadata-and-Validation-with-ASPNET-MVC2/)
>
> Posted By: Jonathan Carter | Jan 7th @
>   11:21 AM
>
> In this episode of 10-4, we discuss a
>   new feature coming in the next release
>   of ASP.NET MVC: model metadata and
>   validation. This allows you to
>   associate validation rules and
>   metadata with your model and have the
>   runtime perform validation
>   automatically. In addition, you can
>   also have JavaScript emitted that will
>   provide client-side validation as
>   well, making it dead simple to achieve
>   a rich client and server validation
>   experience with any web application.